# Can there be a true dual-CPU & dual-memory laptop?

Tags: multi-processor, docking

The [ASUS Transformer Book Trio TX201LA](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_Transformer_Book_Trio_TX201LA/specifications/) is a dual-processor, dual-memory, dual-storage laptop which also runs 2 different operating systems. But can one,somehow, run just one instance of Windows 8.1 on it?

There are [detachable laptops](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/ads/detachables/products.html) with dual-storage running just one instance of Windows 8.1. What would it take on the Operating system's part to identify additional CPU's and channels of memory on the fly so one could utilize additional memory and processing power when the tablet is docked ?

Comment: There are known ways of adding CPUs and memory channels on the fly. The sticking point would be that the hardware implementation would have to be completely different. Modern operating systems that PCs use only support [SMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So which `hardware protocol` must the OS support in order to achieve this. Is there any OS that is currently capable of adding CPUs and memory channels on the fly ? Can I install it on the TX201LA ?

Comment: There are OSes capable of doing that. Linux is, for example. But the TX201LA isn't SMP. So adding memory or adding CPUs won't help, since the memory isn't in the same address space and the CPUs aren't on the same bus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This** laptop is basically 2 completely independent devices.
With the ability to use the LCD panel of the tablet as LCD monitor for the PC.

It is simply not possible to run 1 OS on 2 independent devices. No OS in existence can do that.

The ones you mention in the second paragraph are just 1 device (in the tablet part) that can use additional hardware contained in the base/docking-station (like keyboard, extra HDD, etc.)
This is no different than a normal laptop with extra hardware in the docking-station.

The extra hardware in the dock doesn't include CPU and/or RAM as those are in general not hot-pluggable (in Windows that is... Some other OS do have that ability.)

Even if the OS supports hot-plugging of CPU and/or RAM it would be technically next to impossible to do it in a tablet/laptop type of device.
The functionality is normally only used in virtual environments where the hyper-visor can adjust the specifications of a virtual machine "on the fly".
Doing it with physical hardware would be incredibly difficult. The electrical issues of connecting/disconnecting a CPU and/or RAM "on the fly", are extremely complicated. There exist some server-grade hardware that can do it, but it is VERY expensive stuff.
(This is not to be confused with adding/removing server-blades in a blade server. The blades are each standalone computers with their own CPU/RAM. The connection with the blade back-plane is a special bus system that is designed for hot-plugging.)

Comment: Can't the [Windows HPC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/diy-supercomputing-how-to-build-a-small-windows-hpc-cluster?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) be leveraged to achieve this at a software level ?